# Script component error

Tags: ssis

I'm passing a dataset (query) in SSIS to a script component. However I'm getting an error on execution "Script component has encountered an exception in user code:". I've found other posts with this same error but none of them apply to my error.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    string[] addresses = (Row.shcladdress).Split(';');
}
```

Comment: I actually worked it out. When shcladdress is null, the error comes up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to call the Split method on a nullable structure.

I'd wager dollars to dumplings that the `Row.shcladdress_IsNull` property is true for the failing row(s). Try this code

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{

    string[] addresses = null;
    if (!Row.shcladdress_IsNull)
    {
        // you will probably want to wrap this in a try/catch block as well
        addresses = (Row.shcladdress).Split(';');
    }
    else
    {
        // logic here for empty addresses
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right - refer to my initial comments to my questions. But I'll still give you the points :)